# Creating a searchable phone directory in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, user-profile

We are using SharePoint 2013 and have setup the user profile sync with AD.

Is there a way to create a phone book in SharePoint?

I have found an [OOTB solution](http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2013/05/how-to-create-a-simple-sharepoint-2013-people-directory/). I am following this article.

1. I have created an [enterprise search site collection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582314%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
2. Enabled the people search page layout so we can create a people search results page. This can be done by navigating to the Site Settings > Look and Feel | Page layouts and site templates page and selecting ‘(Welcome Page) Search People’ in the Page Layouts section.
3. The next step is to navigate to the pages library and select New Document > Page from the ribbon.
4. On the create page screen select the Search People page layout to create a page that contains the people search results web parts.
5. The standard search result web part does not show any results unless a query is specified. To get all people to show up by default we need to modify the query used by the People Search Core Results web part. This can be done by clicking the ‘Change Query’ button in the web part properties and adding a property filter that returns all people. To do this we can select the property ‘contentclass’ and enter the manual value ‘spspeople’.

The above step does not show up any users. Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: If you do a search for a particular person, does anyone show up in search results?

Comment: If you read the last line on the question it says "The above step does not show up any users. Any idea what I am missing?"

Comment: Yes, but the above step was an attempt to show all people. So I'm not sure if its the "show all" that's failing, or if search doesn't have any content for people at all. So for example, you said the sync has been configured. I assume this means that user profiles have been confirmed to exist in SharePoint. (they can be viewed via central admin). The next thing to check is the crawler. Is the crawler configured to crawl the user profiles? Has the crawler run successfully? (There should be a content source for: sps3://My_Site_host_URL, and check it's crawl log)

Comment: USer profiles have been confirmed: Yes. Search crawler: Not sure about this. Due to some tricky requirements we had to develop this via code and not OOTB.

Comment: So keep in mind, the results are not pulling from the user profile service, it's pulling from search.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link and be happy :)

http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2013/05/how-to-create-a-simple-sharepoint-2013-people-directory/

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)